# Kernel Dies in Jupyter running on PySpark for R and rJava

Tags: java, r, hadoop

I have a unique setup. For our data scientists at work, I'm trying to get Jupyter running on an HDP 2.5 setup (already done) with R connecting to Hive via JDBC using RJDBC. Whenever I run .jinit() in R, the Kernel dies with the following message:

"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

No error output of any kind. Been googling and searching for days and nothing.

Here it he code I'm trying to run:

```
library('RJDBC')
hadoop.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-
37/hadoop"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hive.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hive-
client/lib"),pattern="jar", full.names=T);
hadoop.lib.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hive-
client/lib"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);
mapred.class.path = list.files(path=c("/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-mapreduce-
client/lib"),pattern="jar",full.names=T);
cp = c(hive.class.path,hadoop.lib.path,mapred.class.path,hadoop.class.path) 
.jinit(classpath=cp,parameters=
"Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false")
```

Please note, this works fine outside of Jupyter.

Comment: _"No error output of any kind"_ >> are you joking?? The Jupyter web server has to spit out its logs somewhere. Check the docs for the default location of that log file. And optionally, change the conf to raise the logging level to DEBUG.

Comment: I'm not joking. There are no errors. There's a log that informs me that kernel has died. I'll attempt to raise the level to debug.